# jquery plugin 'Shorten' specifications doesn't change with "window.width()"

Tags: jquery

I'am trying to use a simple jquery plugin, 'Shorten' (https://www.viralpatel.net/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/) to reduce my text blocks with a 'read more' at the end of it.

I need to reduce the characters shown in Mobile view and Iam using `if($(window).width() < 800)` to tackle this as follows.

```
$(".comment").shorten({ 
        showChars : 500, ellipsesText: "...", moreText  : "Read More", lessText : "Read Less",
 });

   if($(window).width() < 800){
        $(".comment").shorten({ 
            showChars : 100, ellipsesText: "", moreText : "More", lessText  : "Less",
        });
   }
```

However this isn't working and there is no difference in the parameters specified in mobile view.

To make sure the problem is only in this particular plugin, I also tried introducing a background color in mobile view and also another popular jquery plugin 'Select2' into the mobile view code and they work in mobile view:

```
if($(window).width() < 800){
        $(".comment").css('background-color', 'red');
        $(".comment").shorten({ 
            showChars : 100, ellipsesText: "", moreText : "More", lessText  : "Less",
        });
        $("#MultipleSelect").select2({ width: '100%' });
    }
```

Any idea why the 'shorten.()' wont work with different parameters in mobile view?

Find below working code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".comment").css('background-color', 'blue');
    $(".comment").shorten({ 
        showChars : 500, ellipsesText: "...", moreText  : "Read More", lessText : "Read Less",
        });


    if($(window).width() < 800){
        $(".comment").css('background-color', 'red');
        $(".comment").shorten({ 
            showChars : 100, ellipsesText: "", moreText : "More", lessText  : "Less",
        });
        $("#MultipleSelect").select2({ width: '100%' });
    }

});
```

```css
.comment{
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.viralpatel.net/demo/jquery/jquery.shorten.1.0.js"></script>

<body>
        <div class="comment more">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
            quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.<br />
            Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
            blandit id luctus felis convallis.
            Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
            Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.<br />
            Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
            blandit id luctus felis convallis.
            Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
            Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.<br />
            Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
            blandit id luctus felis convallis.
            Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
            Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.<br />
            Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
            blandit id luctus felis convallis.
            Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
            Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.<br />
        </div>
        <select id="MultipleSelect">
            <option>Hello</option>
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>Whats</option>
            <option>Up</option>
        </select>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code *is* working, however, because a `.shorten` style has already been applied, the second is not applied.

You can see this by "more"-ing then "less"-ing your text and the label changes from "Read More" (wide version) to "Less"/"More" (narrow version).

A quick look at the source code on the page you provided has:

```
if($this.hasClass("shortened")) return;
```

which confirms that if it's already been "shortened" it will skip applying new css / the different label.

Your simplest solution will be to only apply the "wide" version when *not* applying the "narrow" version:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log($(window).width())

  if ($(window).width() < 800) {
  
    // apply the "narrow" version
    
    $(".comment").css('background-color', 'pink');
    $(".comment").shorten({
      showChars: 100,
      ellipsesText: "",
      moreText: "More",
      lessText: "Less",
    });
    $("#MultipleSelect").select2({
      width: '100%'
    });
    
  } else {
  
    // apply the "wide" version
    
    $(".comment").css('background-color', 'lightblue');
    $(".comment").shorten({
      showChars: 500,
      ellipsesText: "...",
      moreText: "Read More",
      lessText: "Read Less",
    });

  }

});
```

```css
.comment {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.viralpatel.net/demo/jquery/jquery.shorten.1.0.js"></script>

<body>
        <div class="comment more">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
            quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.<br />
            Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
            blandit id luctus felis convallis.
            Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
            Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.<br />
            Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
            blandit id luctus felis convallis.
            Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
            Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.<br />
            Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
            blandit id luctus felis convallis.
            Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
            Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.<br />
            Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
            blandit id luctus felis convallis.
            Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
            Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.<br />
        </div>
        <select id="MultipleSelect">
            <option>Hello</option>
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>Whats</option>
            <option>Up</option>
        </select>
    </body>
```